# How to separate into diff projects docker-compose architecture and individual projects?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am new to docker-compose and I am trying to create an architecture that can be utilized by multiple projects. Imagine my 2 services are airflow and postgres. I would like to be able to version control my architecture separated from my projects.

For instance, currently I have projects: **project_architecture** and **project_individual**.

- project_architecture includes all my docker information, like docker-compose.yml
- project_individual is a python project where I have functions to get data and transform it

The reason I want to be able to separate these projects is that I can have diff repos and version control for each one independently instead of having coupled with each other. Moreover, if I am successful, I could create new "individual" projects and reuse the architecture.

```
project_architecture:
── README.md
├── config
│   ├── airflow_container.env
│   ├── postgres.env
├── docker-compose.yml
├── services
│   └── postgres
│       ├── 00_create_user.sh
└── shared
    ├── airflow_requirements.txt
    ├── dags
    │   ├── example_dag.py
```

```
project_individual:
├── __init__.py
├── data
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── data.py
├── docker
│   ├── create_main_tables.sql
│   └── my_specific_dag.py
├── func
│   ├── __init__.py
|   └── functions.py
```

If you see closer, I have a docker folder on my individual_project where I was planning to develop its own DAGs and database scripts that will be used on the project_architecture Airflow and Postgres respectively. Moreover, I would want to call specific functions, methods, classes from my project like that on *data/data.py*.

Currently, on my docker-compose.yml file, I am trying to mount an external DAG like this (this does not work):

```
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/../project_individual/docker/my_specific_dag.py:/usr/local/airflow/dags/my_specific_dag.py
```

I have to think the problem I am describing has been solved by companies using container solutions with airflow. I can imagine that there would be a team managing a central airflow while developers generate their projects on their own squad decouple from the architecture. I am happy to take any advice or recommendation. My end goal is to make sure my 2 projects are not coupled and I can expand the projects that can reuse the same architecture (described on project_architecture)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably add more services for each of your individual projects to your docker compose, but if you want to separate deployment, the easiest way would be to create multiple docker-compose files.

This way, you could have a docker-compose.common.yml file detailing your common services, then use the `extends` step of docker-compose to customize your configurations.

You can even call multiple docker-compose files at once during a `docker-compose up` using the `-f` option :

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up -d`